# A string parses as class for set "db.Set<Class>"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-core-7.0

I want to db.Set to query different tables dynamically.
I have many entity models such as User, Invoice, Address or Product classes.
How can I parse string "User" to become a class then db.Set? which can be set dynamically.

I have tried:

```
if (s=="User")
  db.Set<User>...
else if (s=="Invoice")
  db.Set<Invoice>...
```

.. above and so on...

Any solutions that make it simple as db.Set< s >?
It means "s" can directly string to its Class.

Comment: Would be possible with reflection, but think about it: what would you do with such a construct? As the compiler does not know the type, you cannot access any of its members (except again using reflection).

Comment: Yes, seems reflection, but the question is how to code to parse string "User" to become a class not a class's instance!

Comment: [Type.GetType()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.gettype) helps you get the `Type` object. Then you can construct the generic type `DbSet<T>` from it using `Type.MakeGenericType()`. But again: what do you want to accomplish?

Comment: The purpose is to parse string to reflect a class, and use in db.Set<Class>, otherwise i need to if.. else if.. else if.. to check string.